# POI Lectura decimales

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Tengo un excel `*.xlsx` con una celda de tipo `Número`, el valor que tengo en el excel es `0,0794497914814776` pero el valor que me devuelve el metodo `celda.getNumericCellValue()` es: `0,07944979148147759987`

He probado a convertir la celda en texto antes de leerla, pero me arroja una excepcion:

```
celda.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
String a = celda.getStringCellValue();
```

Esto que muestro me sirvió para leer otro excel, con un formato de celda personalizado.

El principal problema que tengo es que la celda puede contener 5, 10 o 15 decimales y necesitamos respetar el valor que viene en el excel.

¿Se puede leer el valor exacto de la celda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un problema del manejo de coma flotante, que pasa en cualquier lenguaje de programación, te pongo un ejemplo en Java:

```js
const valor1 = .0794497914814776;
const valor2 = .07944979148147759987;

console.log ('La diferencia entre',valor1,'y', valor2,'es', valor1 - valor2);
```

Para transformar a texto puedes probar con [NumberToTextConverter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/NumberToTextConverter.html), una clase creada para hacer precisamente lo que intentas.

Comment: Al final era por el excel, al copiar el valor `0.07944979148147759987` muestra solo `0.0794497914814776` por eso al usar el metodo me devolvia mas numeros.. Gracias